# If $E\subset[0,1]$, $|E|=0$ and $f(x)=x^3$, show $|f(E)|=0$, where $|E|$ denotes Lebesgue measure of $E$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is

> If $E\subset[0,1]$, $|E|=0$ and $f(x)=x^3$, show $|f(E)|=0$, where |E| denotes Lebesgue measure of $E$.

Can anyone provide a hint on this? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: The Mean Value Theorem or whatever shows that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le3|x-y|$ for $x,y\in[0,1]$. (Now say you've covered $E$ by open intervals of total length less than $\epsilon$...)

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the set $E$ is of measure zero, for all $\epsilon > 0$ you can find a countable union of open segments $I_n$ with $$E \subset \cup_{n \ge 0} I_n$$ and $$\sum_{n \ge 0} \ell(I_n) < \epsilon$$ That is the definition of $E$ having a measure equal to zero.

You have to prove the same thing for $f(E)$.

Comment: I solved it. Thank you!